# VBA search for value on next sheet

Tags: vba, excel

is there I way for searching a value on the next sheet (ActiveSheet.Next.Activate) without jumping on to it?

Here the whole Code:
the problem is, it jumps to the next sheet even if there is no searched value.

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Loc As Range
    Dim StrVal As String
    Dim StrRep As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    i = 1
    Call Replacing
    End Sub

    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    i = 2
    Call Replacing
    End Sub

    Public Sub Replacing()
        StrVal = Userform1.Textbox1.Text
        StrRep = Me.Textbox1.Text
        if Trim(StrVal) = "" Then Exit Sub
        Dim fstAddress As String
        Dim nxtAddress As String

        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            With ws
                Set Loc = .Cells.Find(what:=StrVal)
                fstAddress = Loc.Address
                If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
                    If Not StrRep = "" And i = 1 Then
                        Loc.Value = StrRep
                        Set Loc = .Cells.FindNext(Loc)
                    ElseIf i = 2 Then Set Loc = Range(ActiveCell.Address) 
                        Set Loc = .Cells.FindNext(Loc)
                        nxtAddress = Loc.Address
                        If Loc.Address = fstAddress Then
                            ActiveSheet.Next.Activate '****Here it should jump only if found something on the next sheet****
                            GoTo repeat
                            nxtAddress = Loc.Address
                        End If
                        If Not Loc Is Nothing Then Application.Goto ws.Range(nxtAddress), False
                    End If
                    i = 0
                End If
            End With
            Set Loc = Nothing
    repeat:
        Next ws
    End Sub
```

the variable "i" which switches between the values 0, 1 and 2 is bound to two buttons. these buttons are "Replace" and "Skip (to next found value)".

Comment: What's the code meant to be doing?  You've got `ActiveSheet` mixed in there with references to the `ws` sheet.  They could be different sheets.

Comment: the code is supposed to find a value, replace it or skip to next value and replace the found value with a new one in every existing sheet, in the workbook.

Comment: Ah, right... so `StrVal` is the searched for value, `StrRep` is the replacement value and `i` is whether to _Replace_ or _Skip_.  What's the third `i` value for - you say 0, 1 and 2?  Where does it decide what the value of `i` is?  The code will just run through all instances of `Loc` - it's not pausing to ask what you want done with the next found value.

Comment: What I did was `Private sub CommandButton1_Click()
i = 1
call replacelogic
End Sub`

`Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
i = 2
Call replacelogic
End Sub`
in the end of the code of replacelogic what I've posted the `i` switches to 0 so you have to press again a button to replace or skip. That's because I didn't want to change all found values at once.

Comment: Looking at the way you've coded it it will run through all instances in the workbook using either 1 or 2 - so will skip all, or replace all.  Looks like you need it to pause at each found value and ask?

Comment: It usually asks you can try the code. :)

Comment: The code isn't complete to try - definitely not an [MCVE].

Comment: so do you want the whole code to try?

Comment: simply after `Loc.Address = fstAddress` it will run `ActiveSheet.Next.Activate`... as the condition just goes for address without the sheet-ref it will run this if the column and row are the same which is the case if it only is found one time at that sheet

Comment: also inside the `If Not Loc Is Nothing Then` there is `i = 0` so it will do the `i = 2` part only once (then run all sheets without doing anything)

Comment: lol, just noticed an error in the source for this code -  [Range Find Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel):  `Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress` If `c` _is_ nothing then `c.Address` fails with an `Object variable or With block variable not set`.

Comment: now you could try the code its all I have

Comment: @DirkReichel That's true it runs through all sheets without doing anything. any solutions? sorry I'm new in VBA.

Comment: if you do not want to do anything anymore, you can do an `Exit For` to skip the loop (code will jump to the first line after the `Next`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code asks on each occurrence of `StrVal` whether you want to replace the value or skip it.

I found a problem checking if `Found_Address = First_Found_Address`:

- If you've replaced the value in in `First_Found_Address` it won't find that address again and miss the starting point in the loop.

Also the original source of the code stops at the last value using `Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress`.  The problem here is that if the value in `c` is being changed eventually `c` will be `Nothing` but it will still try and check the address of `c` - causing an error ([Range Find Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel)).

My solution to this is to build up a string of visited addresses on the sheet and checking if the current address has already been visited using `INSTR`.

I've included the code for calling from a button click or from within another procedure.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    FindReplace Userform1.Textbox1.Text, 1

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    FindReplace Userform1.Textbox1.Text, 1, Me.Textbox1.Text

End Sub

Sub Test()

    FindReplace "cd", 1, "ab"

End Sub

Sub FindReplace(StrVal As String, i As Long, Optional StrRep As String = "")

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Loc As Range
    Dim fstAddress As String

    Dim bDecision As Variant

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Reset the visited address list on each sheet.
        fstAddress = ""
        With ws
            Set Loc = .Cells.Find(what:=StrVal, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
            If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
                Do
                    fstAddress = fstAddress & "|" & Loc.Address

                    Loc.Parent.Activate 'Activate the correct sheet.
                    Loc.Activate        'and then the cell on the sheet.

                    bDecision = MsgBox("Replace value?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Replace or Select value?")

                    If bDecision = vbYes Then
                        Loc = StrRep        'Raise the blade, make the change.
                                            'Re-arrange it 'til it's sane.
                    End If

                    Set Loc = .Cells.FindNext(Loc)

                    If Loc Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                Loop While InStr(fstAddress, Loc.Address) = 0
            End If
        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Works! but it deletes on vbYes and skips on vbNo(which is what I Want)
I can work with that! Thank You!

Comment: what is the `1` for at userform1.textbox3.text, 1 ?

Comment: Was about to comment that you could remove `1` as it's not used.  Also remember to take it out of the procedure name arguments as well.

Comment: For the `vbYes` etc you just need to change the `MsgBox` text and change `If bDecision = vbYes Then` to `If bDecision = vbNo Then`.  You could add more info to the messagebox:  `bDecision = MsgBox("Replace '" & StrVal & "' in '" & Loc.Parent.Name & "'!" & Loc.Address & " with '" & StrRep & "'?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Replace or Select value?")`.  _Feel free to tick the answer if it's the accepted answer_.

Comment: A bit more explanation:  The `1` in `userform1.textbox3.text, 1` is the second argument to be passed to the `FindReplace` procedure.  The procedure accepts three arguments in it's name - with the third being optional (if not given an empty string is used instead) so `Userform1.Textbox1.Text, 1` is passing the value of `TextBox1` to `strVal` and `1` to `i`.  The `Test` procedure passes `cd` to `strVal`, `1` to `i` and `ab` to `StrRep`.

Comment: Genius! Thank You! I had a headache because of this problem since 3 days I'm trying to figure out how to solve this problem. The thing is I'm new at VBA.

Comment: I know the feeling :)